# Get a unique hash value based on value of 3 columns of a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Say I have 3 columns in a table `column_1,column_2,column_3`.

I want to populate two new tables `table_1.column_unique_ind` and `table_2.column_unique_ind`  with a unique value for each unique combination of `column_1,column_2,column_3`.

I want to compare these two columns later on to check for unique combination of column_1,column_2,column_3.

**Is there any built in oracle function which I can use in this case?**

What I want is,

1. For Any given combination of column_1,column_2,column_3 the
       function should always return the same unique value, any day I use this function.
2. For two different combinations of column_1,column_2,column_3 the
       function should always return different value

Comment: Hash values aren't generally unique.  What's wrong with just holding the 3 columns with a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Yes, we can use a unique key on the tables, but, just wondering, is there any way to get a unique hash value in Oracle? 
Also,this way, later on, my sql queries get simpler whenever I want to compare the values of the two tables.

Comment: Can the same combination of `column_1,column_2,column_3` appear more than once in the original table - presumably not if you could add a unique constraint? So, why not just have a synthetic primary key, and use that as a foreign key in your new tables? There's no particular reason that key would need to be a hash of the values, is where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in Oracle feature that I'm aware of that does what you're asking. Here's how I'd go about it (change your variable sizes/types/delimiter as needed).

Create a function to build the unique ID so you can re-use it to get the these ID's as needed.

```
FUNCTION get_unique_id(val_1_in VARCHAR2, val_2_in VARCHAR2, val_3_in VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    unique_id VARCHAR2(4000);
    delimiter_l CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := '|';
BEGIN
    unique_id := val_1_in || delimiter_l || val_2_in || delimiter_l || val_3_in;

    return unique_id;
END;
```

Now, to load your table. I tested this with a temp table and it worked.

```
DECLARE
  unique_id_l VARCHAR2(4000); --consider using table_1.column_unique_id%TYPE
BEGIN
FOR rec in 
   ( --use your 3 columns here you want to make the unique value
    SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3
    FROM source_table
    GROUP BY col_1, col_2, col_3 --this GROUP BY will insure uniqueness
   )
    LOOP
        unique_id_l := get_unique_id(rec.col_1, rec.col_2, rec.col_3); --use your function to build the unique ID we want to submit into the new tables

        INSERT INTO table_1 (column_unique_id)
        VALUES (unique_id_l);
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCAT function:

```
DECLARE
  n1  NUMBER := 1234;
  n2  NUMBER := 567;
  n3  NUMBER := 890;
  c   VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  c := CONCAT(CONCAT(n1, '|'), CONCAT(CONCAT(n2, '|'), CONCAT(n3, '|')));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('''' || c || '''');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.